# Azure Service Bus Authorization Rule - Request to a downlevel service failed

Tags: azure, azureservicebus

I'm getting unusual, but repeatable behaviour, when creating an azure service bus Shared Access Policy and the authorization rules. I create the policy and it's OK. I then attempt to update the authorization rules and it's OK. I then attempt updating the authorization rules again, only this time it fails. In the examples, I'm not changing the rules themselves, just running the same command twice.

```
Import-Module Azure

Import-AzurePublishSettingsFile "C:\MyPublishSettings.publishsettings"

Select-AzureSubscription -SubscriptionId '111-222-333-444-555-666-777-888-999'

New-AzureSBAuthorizationRule -Namespace 'myServiceBusNamespace' -Name 'MyProfileName' -Permission $('Manage','Send','Listen') | Out-Null
-succeeded

Set-AzureSBAuthorizationRule -Namespace 'myServiceBusNamespace' -Name 'MyProfileName' -Permission $('Manage','Send','Listen') | Out-Null
-succeeded

Set-AzureSBAuthorizationRule -Namespace 'myServiceBusNamespace' -Name 'MyProfileName' -Permission $('Manage','Send','Listen') | Out-Null
-error: <string xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/2003/10/Serialization/">Request to a downlevel service failed.</string>
```

As always, stack-overflowers, help muchos appreciated.

Comment: It may be because these action are performed asynchronously ? So you need to wait for each task to complete ?

Comment: Thanks Thomas, I did think that, so left it a while. Came back to it the next day and same error.